# Combine SQL queries for simplicity and performance gains

Tags: mysql, performance

I am trying to combine a few SQL queries to reduce the number of queries performed and hopefully increase performance at the same time.

I have lots of products, split into categories. Some of the products have articles written for them (most don't though). At the moment I fetch all the products for a category a bit like this...

```
// * used here to keep things simple
SELECT * FROM products WHERE iCategory=23;
```

Then, for each product in the resulting list I am doing an additional query like this...

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM articlelinks WHERE iProduct=xxx;
```

If there are 1 or more articles for a product, I can put a little icon next to it.

Can I combine these into a single query that would give me a count for each product, **including the products where the count would be zero**. All my attempts result in a list with that only includes the products with an article.

I am using MySql and PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a  [(scalar) subquery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/scalar-subqueries.html) to get the count for each "group".

```
SELECT
  *,
  (
    SELECT
      COUNT(*)
    FROM
      articlelinks
    WHERE
      articlelinks.iProduct=products.iProduct
  ) as c
FROM
  products
WHERE
  iCategory=23
```

Comment: I've got several correct answers here, so thank you everyone. I am accepting this one as this solution fits into the existing code more easily, though the others are just as correct.

Comment: (As always) better check your query with `EXPLAIN SELECT ....` to see if you have the proper indices for this query. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this

```
SELECT iProduct, COUNT(articlelinks.iArticle)
FROM products LEFT JOIN
  articlelinks ON products.iProduct = articlelinks.iProduct
WHERE iCategory=23
GROUP BY iProduct
```

Comment: I seem to get an error at the `COUNT(articlelinks.*)` part of the query.

Comment: See again, i changed it to articlelink.iArticle, the id from your articlelink table

Comment: Yes, that resolved the problem and produces the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a select statement like this :

```
Select iProduct,  
[other cols],    
(select count(*) from articlelinks where iProduct = products.iProduct) as articles  
from products   
WHERE iCategory=23;
```

This should always give you an article count, even if it is zero